# How to move elements in css

Tags: html, css

I wrote a code that I want to open slowly with the mouse when I go on the box, but it opens quickly.

```css
i.twitter {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.sectionTwitter:hover {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 5px rgb(44, 153, 255);
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left mt-5 sectionTwitter">
  <a class="twitter" href="/">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter twitter " aria-hidden="true">Icon</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: which box, can't see any box

Comment: css transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should be using `class=""` instead of `className` unless you are using ReactJs or something similar. use `transition: all 2s;` 2s is the duration in seconds that your transition animation will take effect. refer to the snippet below

```css
i.twitter {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

   .sectionTwitter {
     
     width: 20px; 
     height: 20px;
     background: blue;
     transition: all 2s ease;
 }

.sectionTwitter:hover {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 5px rgb(44, 153, 255);
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left mt-5 sectionTwitter">
  <a class="twitter" href="/">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter twitter " aria-hidden="true">Icon</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I use react.js, that's why I wrote className. Thank you for my friend's help. My problem was solved.

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

Please check which code acts as an answer to your query, but yes to smoothen the abrupt effect caused by `:hover` you may take hep of CSS transition effects.

```css
 i.twitter {
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          top: 4px;
          font-size: 25px;
        }
        .sectionTwitter{
         transition: width 0.5s linear, border 0.5s linear, background-color 0.5s linear;
         ::-webkit-transition: width 0.5s linear, border 0.5s linear, background-color 0.5s linear;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: transparent;
         }
        .sectionTwitter:hover {
          background-color: red;
          width: 200px;
          height: 40px;
          border: solid 5px rgb(44, 153, 255);
          border-radius: 18px;
         
        }
```

```html
<div class="float-left mt-5 sectionTwitter">
  <a class="twitter" href="/">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter twitter " aria-hidden="true">Icon</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

bringing a css transition effect to sudden appearance of the box styles

Answer (score 0):

1. "**className**" is invalid. It should be only "**class**".
2. Add `transition: 1s` to `.sectionTwitter` class for smooth transition. You can change the value `1s` as your preference.

```css
i.twitter {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.sectionTwitter:hover {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 5px rgb(44, 153, 255);
  border-radius: 18px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="float-left mt-5 sectionTwitter">
  <a class="twitter" href="/">
    <i class="fab fa-twitter twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `transition-duration` to the `.sectionTwitter` element:

```css
i.twitter {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.sectionTwitter {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.sectionTwitter:hover {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 5px rgb(44, 153, 255);
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left mt-5 sectionTwitter">
  <a class="twitter" href="/">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter twitter " aria-hidden="true">Icon</i>
  </a>
</div>
```